# rails: need some explanations of collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, selection

I tried to do display a drop-down list using collection_select. However, after searching around for a while I still can't understand how to setup the parameters for this method.

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses
    attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name
end
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :entry
    has_one :address_type
    attr_accessible :type, :city, :state, :street, :zip
end

class AddressType < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :address
    attr_accessible :name
end
```

And I want to display a drop-down list named "AddressType" selected from model "AddressType"
for each address. The only values of "AddressType" are 'Home', 'Work' and 'Other' which are created in seeds.rb. Here's the _form code:

```
.form-inputs
  5     = f.collection_select (:AddressType, :name, AddressType.all, :id, :AddressType)           
  6     = f.input :street
  7     = f.input :city
  8     = f.input :state
  9     = f.input :zip
```

I have no idea how to setup the parameters of collection_select, so my line'5' is definitely wrong. Other Docs and example are so confusing, so can any one explain how can I do it with collection_select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)

```
= f.collection_select (:type, AddressType.all, :id, :name)
```

when you use *`form.collection_select`*, you should omit *object*, e.g.

```
form.collection_select(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can understand better what is going on with collection_select, it works.

Comment: I got a follow-up question, after I hit 'create' button on my new address page with addresstype on, the error says unknown attribute:type, but I definitely included it in its model?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the address types you are getting are fine.

Use the following:

```
@addresses = AddressType.all


f.collection_select ("address_type", "name", @addresses, "id", "name")
```

where,

**AddressType** = Your model,

**name** = Model field name,

**@addresses** = Collection that contains 'Home', 'Work' and 'Other' from the AddressType table,

**id** = value attribute for your option

**name** = display attribute for your option